# Azure functions not triggering suddenly

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

We have a bunch of AzureFunctions(v1) deployed about 4months ago and everything was working ok until yesterday. For some reason, the azure functions stop being triggered by the scheduler. When we restart the functions directly in the portal or make a re-deployment, everything works ok for about 45 minutes. Not sure what's the cause of the issue. We haven't deployed an update in the last 4 months.

Expected behavior

I would expect the functions to run every X minutes (each one has a different cron expression).

Actual behavior

The functions do not run unless I restart in the portal or redeploy the functions.

The signatures looks like this:

```
 [FunctionName("MyFunc")]
 public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log){}
```

and I have cron expressions for:
`"0 */5 * * * *"`,
`"0 */4 * * * *"`,
`"0 */10 * * * *"`,
`"0 */20 * * * *"`

Comment: It could be anything... try finding clues in logs etc.. [starting point for logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring).

Comment: can you post your cron expression in the settings.job file?

Comment: If I have to guess right now, I will say that your opening to many connections, azure functions are pretty limited in that sense, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

Comment: that could be the origin because each function creates its own HttpClient. I will refactor that to see if that works